# When setting up a new laptop, Setup Assistant doesn't see all the data

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, migration-assistant, setup-assistant, target-disk-mode

I'm trying to set up a new Retina MacBook Pro, which is running OS X 10.10, by transferring data from my old MacBook, which is running OS X 10.8.6, via Thunderbolt.  My old laptop is in Target Disk Mode instead of using Migration Assistant due to the OS mismatch (the new machine wouldn't let me migrate with Migration Assistant).  [As far as I can tell, this all matches what Apple says should work.](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872)  However, I have ~350 GB in my home folder, and my new laptop can only see ~50 GB.  What's going on, and is there any way to fix it?

A few things:

1. I tried copying my data once already, but almost nothing got copied (I think even less than the ~50 GB).
2. I can't update my OS on my old laptop, because I don't have enough space.
3. I could try restoring from a Time Machine backup – it seems to see everything that way – but I don't have the right cables, so (until I can get those) I'm looking for a laptop-to-laptop solution over Thunderbolt.  (I have too much data to use Wi-Fi.)

Comment: what about updated apps on the new computer? could it be it is refusing to copy since it can not recognize the files types?

Comment: @Buscar웃: I'm not sure what you're asking.  At any rate, new computer hasn't completed the OS setup yet – there are no apps, no users, nothing.

Comment: You can migrate from target disk mode, what error did you get when you tried?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't get an error, it just doesn't see all of my data.

Comment: see this: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202910 "Re-download or reinstall any other applications you've purchased from third parties using the instructions provided by the developer of the software you're using. " BEFORE transfer.

Comment: @Buscar웃: I see.  But those are the instructions for manual migration; I'm using Setup/Migration Assistant, which should obviate the need to deal with that.  It's not that it refuses to copy, it's that it thinks my home directory is about seven times smaller than it actually is.

Comment: I think if it can not determine what the file type is, it will ignore it (otherwise it would not know what to do with it and where to place it). The 50GB you have are Apple apps types?

Comment: @Buscar웃: I don't know what the 50 GB are, it doesn't display that.  But there's nothing about any file restriction [in their documentation about Setup/Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872), and indeed, that would be a very weird restriction (all it has to do with the files is put them back where they were before).  And again, if I look on my Time Machine drive, it sees all my files, even though there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Was there a screen to select WHAT information you wanted Transferred? http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872

Comment: @Buscar웃: Yes; it looks like the picture in step 7 of the the "Thunderbolt or FireWire" section of [the article I linked](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872).  When I click the little triangle next to my user name to expand things out, I can see the directories in my home folder, but I can't expand any folders more deeply, and all the directories seem to be there at first glance (I have too many directories to really tell without doing a really exhaustive comparison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While preparing for one last Time Machine backup, I found myself restarting both my old *and my new* laptop – and some combination of these things fixed the problem.  I was able to restore from my old laptop overnight, and this answer is being posted from my new machine.  If anybody has any further insight, I'd welcome it, but my problem is solved!